# How to resolve this Syntax Error '(' unexpected in unix?

Tags: unix, ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh 
arr=(1 2 3 4 5);
echo "${arr[*]}"
```

The above script name is num.sh

I tried to execute this script by ./num.sh. But I got syntax error '(' unexpected

I don't know what is the issue in the above script. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That syntax `arr=(1 2 3 4 5)` might be unavailable in your version of korn-shell.

Check if `ksh93` is available on your system and if so, then put that path at the first line of your script.

Otherwise when ksh93 is not available, use the old syntax `set -A arr 1 2 3 4 5`

Also, omit the trailing semicolon , which is only needed when you have multiple statements on the same line.

More details [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/ch06_04.htm).

Comment: Thanks mao. It works .

Comment: And I have one more doubt Can I able to use c like for loop in ksh?                                         Like                                                                                                                                                 for ((expr1;expr2;expr3))                                                                                                                   do                                                                                                                                                       #statement   done